# Invalid object name 'User-Defined-Table-Type'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2

I am getting error:

```
Invalid object name 'UDTT_SuppliersList'.
```

Which is User-Defined table type as:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UDTT_SuppliersList] AS TABLE(
    [SupplierID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Region_Name] [varchar](255) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SupplierID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
GO
```

I am using it (pass as parameter) with StoredProcedures and it is working fine. But today I tried to pass it as parameter to Table-Valued function. Table is created successfully with no errors. But when I try to call that function it is giving me error as mentioned above.

```
declare @tbl_UDTT_SuppliersList UDTT_SuppliersList 
--declare, and assume populated with data

select* from dbo.GetSupplierInvoicesByDate(@tbl_UDTT_SuppliersList)
```

Here is the function code:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSupplierInvoicesByDate]
(
    @tbl_UDTT_SuppliersList as dbo.UDTT_SuppliersList READONLY
)
RETURNS 
@tableList TABLE(
    SupplierID int,
    InvoiceAmount decimal(19, 3)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tableList (
        SupplierID, 
        InvoiceAmount
    )

    SELECT 
    inv.SupplierID as SupplierID
    ,inv.Amount as InvoiceAmount
    FROM dbo.Invoices inv
    inner join UDTT_SuppliersList tSupp on tSupp.SupplierID = inv.SupplierID
    WHERE inv.IsPaidFully = 0

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: Show function code and try: `declare @tbl_UDTT_SuppliersList dbo.UDTT_SuppliersList`

Comment: function code added in question

Comment: But this is another function`Reports_GetSupplierInvoicesByDate` or it is the same as `GetSupplierInvoicesByDate`?

Comment: yes it same, sorry was my mistake

Comment: Are you sure your type is defined in database you currently use?

Comment: sure, I tried in another sql script, it is working, but when i passed same as parameter to function it is giving me this error. if i comment the call to this function. remaining script is working ok.

Comment: It is strange, show entire script, maybe there will be clue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95569/discussion-between-m-idrees-and-lad2025).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your function:

```
 SELECT 
     inv.SupplierID as SupplierID
    ,inv.Amount as InvoiceAmount
 FROM dbo.Invoices inv
 inner join UDTT_SuppliersList tSupp       -- use use type, not table variable
    on tSupp.SupplierID = inv.SupplierID
```

should be:

```
SELECT 
     inv.SupplierID as SupplierID
     ,inv.Amount as InvoiceAmount
FROM dbo.Invoices inv
JOIN @tbl_UDTT_SuppliersList tSupp 
  ON tSupp.SupplierID = inv.SupplierID;
```

You may wonder why `SQL Server` allows that, answer is simple **[`Deferred Name Resolution`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)**:

> When a stored procedure is created, the statements in the procedure
>   are parsed for syntactical accuracy. If a syntactical error is
>   encountered in the procedure definition, an error is returned and the
>   stored procedure is not created. If the statements are syntactically
>   correct, the text of the stored procedure is stored in the
>   sys.sql_modules catalog view.
>
> When a stored procedure is executed for the first time, the query
>   processor reads the text of the stored procedure from the
>   sys.sql_modules catalog view and checks that the names of the objects
>   used by the procedure are present. **This process is called deferred
>   name resolution because table objects referenced by the stored
>   procedure need not exist when the stored procedure is created, but
>   only when it is executed.**

Consider using inline syntax for better performance:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSupplierInvoicesByDate](
    @tbl_UDTT_SuppliersList as dbo.UDTT_SuppliersList READONLY)
RETURNS  TABLE
AS
RETURN (SELECT 
         inv.SupplierID AS SupplierID
         ,inv.Amount AS InvoiceAmount
        FROM dbo.Invoices inv
        JOIN @tbl_UDTT_SuppliersList tSupp 
          ON tSupp.SupplierID = inv.SupplierID
        WHERE inv.IsPaidFully = 0);
```

I suggest also reading about **[`Inline vs Multistatement Table Function`](http://blog.waynesheffield.com/wayne/archive/2012/02/comparing-inline-and-multistatement-table-valued-functions/)**

Comment: thanks, it works. but thats not good. I think if SQL-SERVER should catch this as error, but is compiled successfully. any how. thanks for helping me to get rid of this problem.

Comment: @MIdrees See update, SQL Server behaves exactly as it should +1